# Angular UI-Calendar scope cannot be updated

Tags: angularjs, scope, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am working on a sample project which involves using the angular-ui calendar. The exact codes I am referencing from is http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ .

If you look at my html code below, the calendar binds to $scope.eventSources, which is an array containing 3 different categories of events. As of now, since I have declared $scope.events as an empty array, the calendar is correctly displaying the other 2 categories of events.

I want to update $scope.eventSources to display the new set of $scope.events when I make a http get request. However, I cannot seem to update the $scope.eventSources.

Pardon my ignorance, but I will greatly appreciate if anybody could shed some light on this issue. Am I missing out something? Or am I getting some concepts wrong? I researched quite a bit before asking this question but I still cannot figure it out.. Thanks a bunch in advance! :)

```
$scope.events = [];

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.surgeries, $scope.eventsF];

$http.get('/clinic/api/appointments/')
    .success(function (data) {      
        $scope.events = data;
        //In the web console, $scope.events now contains all the objects from the HTTP Get Request
        console.log($scope.events);

        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.surgeries, $scope.eventsF];
        //In the web console, $scope.eventSources now contains the new $scope.events objects from the HTTP Get Request
        console.log($scope.eventSources);

        //However, in the view, the $scope.eventSources is not updated with the new objects

        //For Testing: Even if I run this line of code below, the $scope.eventSources still show $scope.surgeries and $scope.eventsF only
        $scope.eventSources = [];

        //For Testing: Even forcing a digest loop does not update the $scope.eventSources
        $timeout(function () {      
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.eventSources = [];
            });
        }, 2000)
    }).error(function (data) {

    });

    //For Testing: However, if I run this line of code below, the $scope.eventSources now do not show $scope.surgeries and $scope.eventsF
    //$scope.eventSources = [];
```

Html Code

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1"
                                 ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Is the calendar a directive? If that's the case, make sure you're using the logic for updates within the directive template itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$scope.events = [];
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.surgeries, $scope.eventsF]; // don't include $scope.events to $scope.eventSources initially

$http.get('/clinic/api/appointments/')
  .success(function (data) {

    $scope.events = data;
    $scope.eventSources.push($scope.events); // when you successfully get new events - add them to eventSources

});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your inputs.

I got it working like this. listOfAppointments is an array of appointment objects. For each appointment, I am pushing it one by one into $scope.events.

```
$http.get('/appointments')

            .success(function (listOfAppointments) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    angular.forEach(listOfAppointments, function (appt) {
                        $scope.events.push(appt);
                    });
                }, 100);
            })

            .error(function () {
                console.log("Some error getting appointments");
            });
```

I performed a timeout as a safety precaution to prevent a scenario where I am pushing in any appointments before the calendar has fully rendered.